# ¿Como abrir una imagen con un boton?

Tags: php, web, imagen, botón

Estoy realizando un proyecto escolar donde tengo que hacer el llamado de una rutina de ejercicios mediante un formulario php.

[image: Este es mi formulario]

Cuando haga click en el boton "**Obtener Rutina**", dependiendo de los valores ingresados en el formulario me debe llamar alguna imagen donde esta la rutina

[image: Imagenes de rutinas]

Esas son la imagenes y la ruta de donde se encuentran es: "C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto_Escuela\img\rutinas"

Pero no se como hacer el llamado, pongo aqui el codigo de mi formulario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UADY - Ingreso de datos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="hijo1">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Ingresa tus datos</h1>

        <form action="../sql/rutina_sql.php" method="post" class="admin-form">

            <h4>Sexo:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Hombre/Mujer" name="sexo" /><br>

            <h4>Peso:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="peso" name="peso" /><br>

            <h4>Edad:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="edad" name="edad" /><br>

            <h4>Presion arterial:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="presion arterial" name="pre_art" /><br>

            <h4>Oxigenacion:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="oxigenacion" name="oxi" /><br>

            <h4>Latidos por minuto:</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="latidos por minuto" name="lat_min" /><br>

            <div class="botones">
                <div class="btnreg">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Obtener Rutina</button>
                </div>

                <div class="btndlt">
                    <a href="../index.php"><button class="btn" type="button">Cerrar sesion</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Estuve tratando con puro **if** ya que no se me ocurrio otra manera, pero no pude y termine desechando ese fichero, despues trate con lo siguiente...

```
<?php
    $peso = $_POST["peso"];
    $edad = $_POST["edad"];
    $pre_art = $_POST["pre_art"];
    $oxi = $_POST["oxi"];
    $lat_min = $_POST["lat_min"];
    $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];

    if ($sexo == "Mujer"){

        $img = "../img/rutinas/rutina_1.jpg";
        $dat = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
        $src = 'data:'.mime_content_type($img).';base64,'.$dat;

        echo "<img src=\"$src\">";

    }
```

?>

Pero tampoco me funciono

Comment: cuales son las condiciones para la llamada de la imagenes? ya que lo que mandas no veo con que se relacionan con las imagenes en si...

Comment: como que las condidicones?
dependiendo de los valores puestos en el formulario me debe abrir alguna imagen
apenas voy en mi segundo año y  no se si haya algun metodo o se tiene que hacer con puro if

Comment: Pues prueba no optimizando _antes_ de hacer que funcione. Si lo haces con puro if y funciona, ya tienes algo para optimizar. Por ahora, no es claro cuál es el criterio en tu código para elegir 1, 2 o 9 en el numeral de las imágenes :)

Comment: ok ya entiendo lo que dicen :)
primero tengo que establecer los parametros para que el codigo elija alguna imagen, yo pensaba que eso se hace mientra voy viendo el funcionamiento
GRACIAS!

Comment: estoy casi seguro que php no tiene botones ... lo botones los tiene html XD